# Check app installs by keyword on Google Play

Tags: android, search, google-play, installation, keyword

Is there any way to check by code if an app was installed from Google Play by search with keyword? For example, I have some app "My Test App", and it can be found by searching "test" in Google Play. Can I detect if user have installed my app by searching this keyword? Or if he used another keyword to find it, can I somehow learn what this keyword was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use InstallReferrerReciver if you want to track via Referrer code
   https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver
2. Monitor User Acquisition Reports via Google Play Store Developer Console -> User Acquisition->Acquisition Reports. Here you can view your reports ( search keywords via google). You can use gsutil (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) if you want to access this programmatically